# Does firebase automatically logs exceptions somewhere in firebase console or crashlytics

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Here I'm not asking about why OTP is not receiving on my phone number. I just wanted to know that is there any way so I can check these FirebaseAuthException logs in the firebase console, maybe in crashlytics section.

```
Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber(String phone) async {
  try {
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phone,
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        /// My question is 'Does firebase stores this exception in firebase console' ? So I can check why OTP verification is being failed on users side.
      },
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120),
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {
     
      },
      verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) {
      },
    );
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication does **not** automatically log errors in API calls anywhere that you can see them. If you want that, you need to log the errors yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I will add logs by myself